# Issue reading text with python-docx when document contains Images

Tags: python, ubuntu, docx, python-docx

I am having issues parsing text from a document that contains images.

I am using version 0.7.0 of Python docx on a Ubuntu Linux machine running Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-60-generic x86_64)

I am using this logic:

```

```
        document = Document(path)
        # Get all paragraphs
        paras = document.paragraphs

        text = ""

        # Push the text from the paragraph on a single string
        for para in paras:
            # Don't forget the line break
            text += "\n" + para.text

        return text.strip()
```

```

When there is an image this process fails.

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: You shall provide here error trace. "Fails" has many meanings. Also, check documentation and known issues for the library to see, if they support parsing documents with images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`python-docx` should support what you're trying to do here. If you'll provide the stack trace you get when the error is raised I'll take a look.

Btw, you can code this a little more elegantly as:

```
document = Document(path)
text = '\n'.join([para.text for para in document.paragraphs])
```

Comment: I can't seem to get it to fail for me with the same file.I will have to do more investigation and see what is causing the issue. We have the call to the python-docx code wrapped in a call from another script that is setup using argparse. I may need to expand the logging down the child scripts and see if I can find out what is causing the problem.